# Select and count votes from a survey table where not all options have votes

Tags: mysql, join, rdbms, one-to-many

I'm struggling with a task that could be very simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I've two database table:

options_table

```
option_id | option_name | question_id |
    1     |   opt one   |      4      |
    2     |   opt two   |      4      |
    3     |   opt three |      4      |
    4     |   opt four  |      4      |
```

and votes_table

```
question_id | survey_id | option_id |
    4       |    1      |     1     |
    4       |    1      |     2     |
    4       |    1      |     2     |
    4       |    1      |     1     |
    4       |    1      |     3     |
    4       |    1      |     2     |
```

From this example, we have 2 votes on option 1, 3 votes on option 2 and 1 vote on option 3, but none on option 4.
I'd like to retrieve all the options name with the relative count, but I can't get the option without votes. I'm sure I'm overlooking something, it's workday's end and I must be tired.
I tried something like:

```
   SELECT o.option_name, count(*) as cnt 
   FROM votes_table AS v 
   JOIN options_table AS o 
   ON o.option_id = v.option_id 
   WHERE v.survey_id = 1 
   GROUP BY o.option_name
```

but I just get

```
option_name | option_id | cnt
 opt one    |   1       |  2
 opt two    |   2       |  3
 opt three  |   3       |  1
```

How do I get also "opt four"? So I can properly display all the survey results including the option noone voted. I also tried using OUTER JOINs, but to no avail.

I'm ashamed for this might sound a stupid question, but I still have a lot to learn on databases and relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT` instead of `INNER` join - put in the Left side the table with all the options, and in the Right side the table with missing options.

Move any condition that uses a column from the Right table, like the `v.survey_id = 1` one, from the `WHERE` to the `ON` clause.

Use `COUNT(RightTable.column)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, so you get `0` for options not voted:

```
SELECT o.question_id
     , o.option_name
     , COUNT(v.option_id) as cnt 
FROM 
    options_table AS o  
  LEFT JOIN 
    votes_table AS v
      ON  v.option_id = o.option_id 
      AND v.question_id = o.question_id
      AND v.survey_id = 1 
WHERE o.question_id = 4            --- if you want results for one question only 
GROUP BY o.question_id
       , o.option_id
```

I suppose that `(option_id, question_id)` is the Primary (or a Unique) Key of the `options` table. That's why you either need to `GROUP BY` both of them or `WHERE o.question_id` and `GROUP BY o.option_id`.

Otherwise, if you only `GROUP BY o.option_id`, the query for every option, will count votes for all questions that were voted with this option.

Comment: This is the closest to the solution. As of now, it fetched also other results than those needed though...I tried adding the condition `..WHERE o.question_id = 4 GROUP BY...` and then it gave me the desired output..

Comment: Still a bit confused though, I need to apply more on databases it seems, but +1 and thanks for the explanations you gave (if you update your answer with the "Where" clause I added, and maybe tell me why the hell it made it work instead of yours, I'll gladly mark this as accepted too :))

Comment: You mean the `WHERE v.survey_id = 1`? What other results does this give you?

Comment: No, I mean `LEFT JOIN votes_table AS v ON ....AND v.survey_id = 1 WHERE o.question_id = 4 GROUP BY o.option_id`. It gave me results from `options_table` even if referring to different questions; that's why I tried specifying the question_id for the `options_table` table

Comment: Yes, adding `WHERE o.question_id = 4` is corerct if you want results only for this question. You colud also change the `GROUP BY o.option_id` to `GROUP BY o.question_id, o.option_id` if you remove that `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  o.option_name, 
  ( SELECT 
      count(*) 
    FROM 
      votes_table 
    WHERE  
      v.survey_id = 1
    AND
      v.question_id = o.question_id
    AND
      v.otion_id = o.option_id 
  ) as cnt 
options_table AS o;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using INNER JOIN (JOIN), you can use LEFT JOIN to achieve this

```
 SELECT o.option_name, count(*) as cnt 
 FROM options_table AS o  
 LEFT JOIN votes_table AS v
 ON o.option_id = v.option_id 
 WHERE v.survey_id = 1 
 GROUP BY o.option_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT o.option_name, count(*) AS cnt 
FROM options_table o 
LEFT JOIN votes_table v ON o.option_id = v.option_id 
WHERE v.survey_id = 1 
GROUP BY o.option_name
```

If you use `INNER JOIN` you only get records having a corresponding item in both tables.